# What is a formal way to write takes money away from consumers?

Tags: formality

The context is that of a macroeconomic report speaking about contractionary fiscal policy:

> This in turn takes money away from consumers therefore, forcing consumers to demand less from businesses.

Comment: Most economists like folksy phrases like *the pound in your pocket*. I think your example is fine for most contexts.

Answer (score 1):

This in turn *reduces the purchasing power of consumers*, therefore forcing them to demand less from businesses.